# I want to split my dataset into a set of features (X) and variable (Y) in python

Tags: python

when i try to define X and Y from my dataset that is already defined and I made some analysis based on it and i dont have any problem.
but when i start to define (X) and (Y), an error message appear that "NameError: name 'MyNewDataSet' is not defined

the dataset name is "MyNewDataSet"
do I need to define a new dataset before assign the values to X and Y? or what should I do

Comment: Can yo show your code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I define X and Y from my dataframe:

```
#Create X
X = MyNewDataSet.drop(['y'], axis=1)
```

For X I am using multiple columns so all I do is remove the column I will be using for my y variable.

```
#Create y
y = MyNewDataSet['y']
```

Here I create Y by assigning the columns y to the variable.

If this does not work please share some of your code. That way it might be easier for us to visualize your problem, but I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

there is my code to define my new dataset

```
 ###KNN imputation to fill missing values.
import numpy as np
from numpy import isnan
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
imputer.fit(MyDataSet)
MyNewDataSet = pd.DataFrame(imputer.transform(MyDataSet), columns = MyDataSet.columns)
MyNewDataSet.set_index(MyDataSet.index, inplace= True)
MyNewDataSet = MyNewDataSet.astype(MyDataSet.dtypes.to_dict())
MyNewDataSet
```

and here is my code to assign values to X and Y

```
  ### Split the dataset into a set of features (X) and Target variable (y)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

y=MyNewDataSet["Target"]
x=MyNewDataSet.drop("Target", axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you defined `MyNewDataSet` within the same file as `x` and `y`? Or if those are separate cells, have you run them one after another? I tried to reproduce your actions and it was alright.